# How can I add border-right to my bottom menu bar?

Tags: html, css

I have following code in website:

```
<table width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr>
<td >Home</td>
<td>About Us</td>
<td>Services</td>
<td>Gallary</td>
<td>Contact Us</td>
<td>Enquiry</td>
</tr>
</table><br/>
```

I want to add border-right in each menu with equal space.  How can I do this?

Comment: `<style>td{border-right:1px solid #000;}</style>`, for example.

Comment: You really shouldn't use tables for layout, use CSS instead. Tables is a dirty way and doesn't go well with screen readers and accessibility.

Comment: Eek! I would suggest not using Tables for anything other than tabular data. If you are just starting HTML and CSS, there is no better resource than HTMLDog.com - please check it out from top to bottom. A single day to make you grow as a developer tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this CSS is what you're asking for:

```
td
  { border-right: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
    }
td:last-child
  { border-right: none; }
```

[Check out this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRxBB/).  Note that the `td:last-child` selector won't work in all browsers.

However, you should really move away from using tables as layout elements.